# Different number of align points from the first line

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I'm trying to get something really simple to work but LaTeX is being annoying.

```
y &= f(x)  \\
z &= y \times && p \\
& \times && q
```

I want the `&&` to be aligned but right now it produces the following:

[image: [annoying latex]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jZoF.gif)

Comment: It would be nice to post a full compilable code. Could help to understand what happens…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can obtain the alignment you seek:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  y &= \mathrlap{f(x)} \\
  z &= y & {}\times{} & p \\
    &    & {}\times{} & q
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
  y &= f(x) \\
  z &= y \times p \\
    &\phantom{{}= y} \times q
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The first uses an `alignat` structure, but requires you to ensure that the first equation doesn't interfere with the alignment of the second/third. The second option inserts the appropriate `\phantom` to have the `\times` aligned.